# Probability mass function and CDF of two dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The random variable X is the result of rolling a 4-sided dice. The random variable Y is also the result of rolling a 6-sided dice.
> a)Consider Z = $(x+y)/2$, what are the PMF and CDF of Z?
> b)Suppose in a game if Y > X, you win 2X dollars and otherwise you lose 1 dollar. after
> Playing this game 60 times, what will be the mean of the amount of money you earned?

for part a I wrote the pmf of Z like this:

$$P_Z(i)=\begin{cases}
0 & i=0.5 \\
\frac{1}{24} & i=1 \\
\frac{2}{24} & i=1.5 \\
\frac{3}{24} & i= 2\\
\frac{4}{24} & i=2.5 \\
\frac{4}{24} & i=3 \\
\frac{4}{24} & i=3.5 \\
\frac{3}{24} & i=4 \\
\frac{2}{24} & i=4.5 \\
\frac{1}{24} & i=5 \\
\ 0 & i=5.5 \\
\ 0 & i=6 \\
\end{cases}$$

and the CDF will be:
$$\sum_{Z_{i}\le z}P_{Z}(i)$$

but I'm not sure about my answers and any hint or help for part b would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, assuming the four sided die is numbered 1-4 and the six sided die is numbered 1-6, I think your pmf for $Z$ is incorrect. For example, if $X=1,Y=2$, then $Z=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y) = \frac{1}{2}(1+2) = \frac{3}{2} = 1.5$, but I don't see $P(Z=\frac{3}{2})$ specified. Moreover, the probabilities specificed in your pmf for $Z$ don't sum to $1$.

Comment: I edited it thank you.

Comment: No problem. Also, your pmf only needs to specify probabilities for outcomes that are possible. In other words, there is no need for your pmf to specify probabilities for outcomes like $Z=6$. If there were such a need, then why not specify probabilities for outcomes like $Z=100$, $Z=100+1$, $...$?

Comment: I just wrote them to make it more understandable.

Comment: The sum of your probabilities should be $1$.  Check your calculation for $\Pr(Z) = 4.5$.

Comment: fixed it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a), I think you are on the right track.

For b), assuming 60 times is enough to approximate the exact mean, the expected money that is earned equals:
$$
P(Y>X)\times 2X + P(Y\le X)\times(-1)
$$

It is not difficult to compute $P(Y\le X)=5/12$. And you can compute $P(Y>X)\times 2X$ as follows:
$$
P(Y>X)\times 2X = \sum_{x=1}^4P(Y>x, X=x)\times 2x
$$
Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you will find that this term equals $5/2$, and so the expected money that is earned equals $25/12$. I will leave you with the details.